# Count elements in alpine.js

Tags: javascript, count, alpine.js

Please find below a simplified example of what I try to achieve.

I have a big list of which I create an overview using alpinejs.

I now added a filter to just show some of my elements.

I also have a global number of elements shown as well as a global count of stuff the elements have.

In below example I show for each client the cars they own and the number of cars they own. Globally I show the number of clients and the total amount of cars.

This works as long as I do not filter.

As soon as filtering starts, the global numbers act weird.

When started, I have 3 clients and 5 cars.

When I enter an `E`, It should be 1 client and 2 cars, but it remains as 3 and 5.

When I remove the `E`, the numbers go up to 8 clients and 12 cars.

I'm sure it is due to the fact that the global counts do not get reset to 0.

But I couldn't find a way to achieve this reset. Any help would be much appreciated.

Please note that I know, I can avoid actually counting the cars with `++individualcount` by just replacing `x-text="individualcount"` with `x-text="cars.length"`.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script defer src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 x-data="{ message: 'I ❤️ Alpine' }" x-text="message"></h1>
<div
    x-data="{
        search: '',
 
        items: [
            {client: {name: 'Hugo', id:'0001' }, stuff: {cars: [ 'Horch', 'Benz' ] } },
            {client: {name: 'Hans', id:'0002' }, stuff: {cars: [ 'Horch'         ] } },
            {client: {name: 'Egon', id:'0003' }, stuff: {cars: [ 'VW', 'Maybach' ] } },
        ],
 
        get filteredItems() {
            return this.items.filter(
                i => i.client.name.startsWith(this.search)
            )
        },
    }"
>
    <input x-model="search" placeholder="Search...">
 
    <ul x-data="{ clientcount : 0, carcount : 0 }">
        <p>Number of clients: <span x-text="clientcount"></span></p>
        <p>Number of cars: <span x-text="carcount"></span></p>
        <template x-for="item in filteredItems" :key="item.client.name">
            <li x-data="{ individualcount : 0 }"
                x-effect="carcount += individualcount; ++clientcount">
                <span x-text="item.client.id"></span>
                <span x-text="item.client.name"></span>
                (<span x-text="individualcount"></span>)
                <ul>
                    <template x-for="car in item.stuff.cars" :key="car">
                        <li x-text="car"
                            x-effect="++individualcount">
                        </li>
                    </template>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </template>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: FYI: I found that it seems to be impossible to achieve what I was looking for. x-for doesn't have something like a for-loop has, i.e. initialization of some values. That would have helped. I solved my issue by changing the "filteredItems" member to do the calculations and have a precalculation in my initialization function.